# Why output doesn't apply the second variable

Tags: javascript, html, function, while-loop, conditional-statements

I'm trying to understand why the variable txt that is equal to 10 does not get applied to the statement when it comes back around? If I set the variable to 10 shouldn't it apply to the output when the loop comes back around?

Here is my code:

```js
function myFunction() {
    var myNumber = 2; 
    var txt = 10;
    while (myNumber != Infinity) {
        myNumber = myNumber * myNumber;
        txt = txt + myNumber + "<br>";
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: It is not clear to me what the problem is. What do you mean with *apply*? What output would you have expected?

Comment: so basically im trying to understand why the first output is equal to 14, but when the function loops back around that txt=10 is not applied to the rest of the output. @trincot

Comment: Before the first iteration, it's the number `10`. After that iteration, it's the sum of `10 + 4` then converted to a string  `<br>` on the end, so `"14<br>"`. So I don't know what output you wanted, but if you were hoping each number would be offset by `10`, it's not because `10` no longer exists.

Comment: @trincot so in other words, if i stated that the var "txt" = 10 what happens to it when the function loops back around? Like where does it go if txt = txt + myNumber?

Comment: If you want 10 to remain invariant, then do `txt = 10 + myNumber + "<br>";`

Comment: When you assign a number to a variable, the previous number that was assigned to it will be gone. So when you have `txt = 10` and then `txt = ...some calculation...`, then that 10 is gone.

Comment: yeah sorry i meant add to or "append"... and @squint ....why does the 10 no longer exist? lol thats what i am having a little trouble understanding

Comment: @trincot ohhhh ok but i thought i had to state that it is a new variable. That makes more sense now.

Comment: @CheckLife: When you assigned to `txt` in the first loop iteration, you replaced the number `10` with the value of the string `"14<br>"`

Comment: Yeah now i completely understand!!! You guys are awesome!!!!! THANKS a ton....im over here sweating bullets! @squint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable does change with every iteration of the loop.

Let's follow the value with every iteration:

`#1 iteration: txt == 10 + 4 + "<br>" == "14<br>"`

`#2 iteration: txt == "14<br>" + 16 + "<br>" == "14<br>16<br>"`

`#3 iteration: txt == "14<br>16<br>" + 256 == "14<br>16<br>256"`

And so on. Also, with each iteration you change the HTML code of your `<p>` completely, in contrast to add to it with `append` for example. Basically the variable txt changes with each iteration, and you display it's last value in your `<p>`

Answer (score 0):

Your `var txt = 10` is not inside the while loop, so it is not being reset after each cycle. I assume your question means you would like to have `txt = 10` each time you run through the while loop, while only `myNumber` increments. If that is the case, you can simplify your code as follows:

```
function myFunction() {
    var myNumber = 2; 
    while (myNumber != Infinity) {
        myNumber = myNumber * myNumber;
        var txt = 10 + myNumber + "<br>";
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
}
```

Comment: yeah no i completely understand why the output is what it is now Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is the break that you're adding to txt. If I understand correctly, this should fix your issue.

```
function myFunction() {
var myNumber = 2; 
var txt = 10;
var output = "";
while (myNumber != Infinity) {
    myNumber = myNumber * myNumber;
    txt = txt + myNumber;
    output = output + txt  + "<br>";
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `var text` that holds the value 10 gets reassigned the value of the string set in the first iteration.

If you logged out `txt` this is what you would see at each iteration:

```
// 1) 14
// Effectively '14<br>`
// A result of 10 + (2*2) + <br>

// 2) 14
//    16
// Effectively '14<br>16<br>`
// This is because txt was '14<br>`
// So '14<br>` + (4*4) + <br>

// 3) 14
//    16
//    256
// Effectively '14<br>16<br>256<br>`
// This is because txt was '14<br>16<br>`
// So '14<br>16<br>` + (16*16) + <br>
```

And so on...

Comment: when you say logged out what are you referring to?

Comment: I was referring to the use of `console.log`